# Kendo Angular Editor setHTML: Insert HTML Content at specific position or after cursor

Tags: angular, kendo-editor, kendo-angular-ui

The available command `setHTML` replaces the existing content.  Is there any way to insert HTML content at specific position as `insertText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research I found that currently there is no built-in way to get this done. However there is a workaround provided at Telerik forums.

Forum link: [insert-html-content-to-editor](https://www.telerik.com/forums/insert-html-content-to-editor)

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fway1h-7ydfj2?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
public insertHTML(editor: EditorComponent) {
editor.exec('insertText', { text: '#CURSOR#' });
// Replace cursor placeholder with new HTML and set the new editor value.
editor.value = editor.value.replace(/#CURSOR#/, this.strResult);
}
```

Comment: Also, it seems that there is an issue when trying to add a [custom Angular element](https://angular.io/guide/elements). E.g. `editor.exec("setHTML", "<custom-img></custom-img>");` will work, while the `editor.exec("setHTML", "<p><custom-img></custom-img></p>");` won't work. Did you come across the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
import { DOMParser as ProseDOMParser } from "prosemirror-model";

public insertHTML(htmlString: string) {
    const view = this.editor.view;
    const state = view.state;

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const tmpNode = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

    const domParser = ProseDOMParser.fromSchema(schema);
    const newNodes = domParser.parse(tmpNode);

    view.dispatch(state.tr.insert(state.selection.head, newNodes));
}
```

The workaround by Telerik did not work for my custom schema properly, this one does.